# Automatically Updating Publish Date Bug

Tags: posts, taxonomy, publish, date-time

I recently added a function to reset the publish date when a user updates a page. The code is as follows, thanks to @s_ha_dum for it because it works great except for one annoying instance.

```
function reset_post_date_wpse_121565($data,$postarr) {
// var_dump($data,$postarr); die; // debug
$data['post_date'] = $data['post_modified'];
$data['post_date_gmt'] = $data['post_modified_gmt'];
return $data;}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','reset_post_date_wpse_121565',99,2);
```

I noticed it works as intended for posts and pages but I have a custom taxonomy where, when I update one item, in this case 'property' it updates the publish date for all of that same taxonomy. Any idea how to avoid this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you save taxonomy or custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

You could also hook into the `save_{$post_type}` action, which fires only when a certain post type is updated. This hook passes to post's ID to the callback function:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_callback_function' );
function my_callback_function( $post_id ){

    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

        // Unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'my_callback_function');

        // Update post's data
          $post = array(
              'ID'              => $post_id,
              'post_date'       => current_time( 'mysql' ),
              'post_date_gmt'   => current_time( 'mysql', 1 ),
          );

        // Update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( $post );

        // Re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'my_callback_function');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely response! 
Unfortunately it is still updating the publishing date for all 'properties'